# update sql table with multi-jojn

Tags: sql

I have the SQL statement below which pulls data from multiple tables, as can be seen that the chapter Id is null in the tblquestions i would like to know how i would update the table so that it shows the chapter id which is being pulled from  with a matching section id in the question table

in turn I want to update the tblQuestions, with the chapterId where the section Id equals that of the section chapterid

```
select chap.chapterID , sec.sectionID, q.ChapterId , q.sectionID from tblChapters as chap
left join tblSections as sec on chap.chapterID = sec.chapterID
left join tblQuestions as q on chap.subjectID = q.subjectID
where chap.subjectID  = 363
group by chap.chapterID, sec.sectionID, q.ChapterId , q.sectionID
```

OutPut

```
chapterID   sectionID   ChapterId   sectionID
22266       4869        NULL         4869
```

Tbl chapter

```
chapterID
subjectID
chapterNo
Title
cssID
OldChapterId
```

tbl sections

```
sectionID
chapterID
sectionNO
Title
cssID
oldSecId
```

tblQuestions

```
 questionID
QuestionType
QuestionNo
question
A
B
C
D
correctAnswer
explanation
bookRef
sectionID
subjectID
syllabusRef
noChapSec
ChapterId
oldChapIf
OldSubID
oldSecId
```

Comment: you do not want to include those results where chapter ID is null in tblquestions ..right ??

Comment: yes i would like to add it there

Comment: please provide schema of the tables

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this :-

```
   update q
set q.ChapterId=t.chapterID
from tblQuestions q Join (
select chap.chapterID , sec.sectionID, q.ChapterId , q.sectionID from tblChapters as chap
left join tblSections as sec on chap.chapterID = sec.chapterID
left join tblQuestions as q on chap.subjectID = q.subjectID
where chap.subjectID  = 363
group by chap.chapterID, sec.sectionID, q.ChapterId , q.sectionID )t on t.sectionID=q.sectionID
```

Comment: The query is working fine, but i would like to update the chapterid on the question table where the q.sectionid is equal to sec.sectionId

Comment: this wont work as its not updating the the table based on section id

Comment: it says multiple time section id was used in t

Answer (score 0):

Try this....

```
UPDATE  tblQuestions q
    SET   q.ChapterId  =  (

    SELECT sec .ChapterId  
    from tblSections sec 
    INNER JOIN tblChapters chap on chap.chapterID = sec.chapterID
    WHERE chap.subjectID = q.subjectID

    )

    WHERE q.ChapterId  IS NULL
```

Comment: this wont work, as it wont add to the chapter id where the sectionid has the chapter id

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE q SET q.ChapterID = chap.ChapterID
FROM tblQuestions q
INNER JOIN tblChapters  chap
ON chap.subjectID = q.subjectID
WHERE q.ChapterId  IS NULL
```